# Pathfinder Olympiad book's question

Tags: inequalities, recreational-mathematics

35. Let $$x_{n}=\sqrt[2]{2+\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[4]{4+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}}};$$ prove that
    $$x_{n+1}-x_{n}<\frac{1}{n !}, \quad n=2,3, \dotsc.$$

Answer (score 4):

For all natural $n\ge2$ we have
\begin{equation}
    x_n=f_n(0),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    f_n(x):=\sqrt[2]{2+\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[4]{4+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n+x}}}}
\end{equation}
for all real $x\ge0$, so that
\begin{equation}
    f_2(x)=\sqrt{2+x}
\end{equation}
and, for $n\ge3$,
\begin{equation}
    f_n(x)=f_{n-1}((n+x)^{1/n}). 
\end{equation}

For real $x>0$ we have
\begin{equation}
    0<f_2'(x)=\frac12\,(2+x)^{-1/2}<\frac1{2^{3/2}}
\end{equation}
and, for $n\ge3$,
\begin{equation}
    0<f_n'(x)=f_{n-1}'((n+x)^{1/n})\frac1n\,(n+x)^{1/n-1}
    <f_{n-1}'((n+x)^{1/n})\frac1{n^{3/2}}.
\end{equation}
So, by induction on $n$,
\begin{equation}
    0<f_n'(x)<\frac1{(n!)^{3/2}}
\end{equation}
for all natural $n\ge2$ and all real $x>0$.
So,
\begin{equation}
    x_{n+1}-x_n=f_{n+1}(0)-f_n(0)\\ 
    =f_n((n+1)^{1/(n+1)})-f_n(0) \\ 
    <(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}\frac1{(n!)^{3/2}}<\frac1{n!}
\end{equation}
for $n\ge3$, because  for $n\ge3$ we have $(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}<(n!)^{1/2}$; in turn, the latter inequality holds for $n\ge3$ because (i) it holds for $n=3$, (ii) $(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}$ is decreasing in $n\ge3$, and (iii) $(n!)^{1/2}$ is increasing in $n\ge3$.

Thus, for $n\ge3$,
\begin{equation}
    x_{n+1}-x_n<\frac1{n!}.
\end{equation}
It is easy to see that the latter inequality holds for $n=2$ as well.

Comment: Answering this type of questions, instead of closing and deleting them, only encourages their authors to ask even more of them. First, this is not a MO-level question. Second, this is neither a MSE-level question, because it shows no attempts at attacking the problem. I believe that you shouldn't have answered this, and I am also amazed by the 2 upvotes of the question.

Comment: @AlexM. : To me, what matters more is whether a question is clearly stated and how nontrivial/interesting the answers to it are. Many such questions can go under the recreational math tag. I think one can find many questions on MO that are clearly not research-level and not as clearly stated and admit easy answers but were nonetheless let be.

Comment: Thank you very much @losif pinelis

Comment: @Harshbhardwaj : You are welcome. Are you satisfied with this answer?